# Adding Objects to JSON file with JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a very simple JSON file called json.php:

```
[ { "name":"wowsk" } ]
```

I want visitors to my website to be able to add objects to the array. What I am stuck on though is, how to allow them to add it. I have an HTML file and the body looks like this:

```
<form id="addName">
    <input id="name" placeholder="Enter your name.">
    <button id="addNameButton" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function addName() {
        var input=document.getElementById("name").value;
        $.ajax({
        url: "json.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data:  {"name":"hello"}
    })
}
$("#addNameButton").click(function() {addName()}) 
</script>
```

The page will not add another object to the file though, and I have also tried  using PUT but that does not work either. Will I not be able to use JQuery to add objects to the file or do I just have a mistake in using the function? I have researched this for multiple days but could not find anything to help.
 Thanks for any help,
Wowsk
 
Also, as a note, I want the file to be changed for others too not just you or your session.

Comment: Do you have a JSON file or a JSON object ?? If you have a file you need to use file IO to read write that if you have a JSON object in your JS scope just push an object in the array

Comment: @Wowsk Take a look at this Q/A: http://goo.gl/tpKzXf

Comment: @NightOwlPrgmr Thanks! That is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need an actual PHP script that adds to the JSON file, it doesn't happen magically.

```
$.ajax({
    url  : "script.php",
    type : 'POST',
    data :  {"name":"hello"}
});
```

And then in `script.php` you'd do something like

```
<?php

    $content = file_get_contents('json.php');

    $json    = json_decode($content, true);

    $json["name"] = $_POST["name"] || "";

    $str     = json_encode($json);

    file_put_contents( 'json.php', $str );

?>
```

This is really verbose, but to make a point, you have to get the JSON, parse it into something usable, add the property, and then convert back to string, and store in the file again.

Comment: I changed the file to use the ajax function you suggested and also added a script.php file.  But when I go to the page: wowsk.org/addName the PHP file does not update when I press submit even though the page alerts to me "success". Is there something that I am doing wrong or do I have a simple misspelling?

Comment: make sure you write permission for the file, that the path and filename is correct etc. You can also debug by returning different values to the ajax function to see what's happening .