# How to push data into an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have object and I am trying to push data into it, but I am getting the error "`push` is not a function".

Here's my object:

```
var item = {
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "asdf976"
  },
  "Categories": [{
    "mainmodels": [{
      "submodels": [{
          "price": "2000",
          "submodelname": "lumia021",
          "Remainingphones": "0",
          "Bookedphones": "0",
          "Numofphones": "10"
        }, {
          "price": "2000",
          "submodelname": "lumia341",
          "Remainingphones": "5",
          "Bookedphones": "5",
          "Numofphones": "10"
        }

      ],
      "Status": "Active",
      "modelname": "lumia",
      "fromdate": "2016-04-01T16:39:12.051Z",
      "todate": "2016-04-31T19:19:44.051Z"
    }],
    "brand": "nokia"
  }],
  "rank": "1",
  "name": "first"
}
```

I want to push:

```
var modal = {
                'custid': '1',
                'packcode': '22'
            };
            item.push(modal);
            console.log(item);
```

Here's my expected result:

```
var item = {
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "asdf976"
  },
  "Categories": [{
    "mainmodels": [{
      "submodels": [{
          "price": "2000",
          "submodelname": "lumia021",
          "Remainingphones": "0",
          "Bookedphones": "0",
          "Numofphones": "10"
        }, {
          "price": "2000",
          "submodelname": "lumia341",
          "Remainingphones": "5",
          "Bookedphones": "5",
          "Numofphones": "10"
        }

      ],
      "Status": "Active",
      "modelname": "lumia",
      "fromdate": "2016-04-01T16:39:12.051Z",
      "todate": "2016-04-31T19:19:44.051Z"
    }],
    "brand": "nokia"
  }],
  "rank": "1",
  "name": "first",
  'custid': '1',
  'packcode': '22'
};
```

How do I do that?

Comment: where does the object belong to?

Comment: you are trying to push to an object. but you need an array for that operation.

Comment: try to check this, [pushing objects to json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32048607/adding-objects-to-json-file-with-jquery)

Comment: That's not JSON. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: It's *absolutely fine* if English isn't your first language and perfect English is *not required* here, at all...but **any** English course will tell you very, very early on that "I" is always capitalized, that sentences start with a capital letter, etc. Don't rush when asking your question. Write it, then read it, take the time to make sure it's clear, properly-formatted, and doesn't have basic errors as far as you know.

Answer (score 0):

You don't `push` into objects, you `push` into arrays.

Based on what you've said you want, you do this:

```
item.custid = '1';
item.packcode = '22';
```

E.g., just assign properties to the object.

In ES2015, you could use `Object.assign` if having `modal` be separate is important:

```
var modal = {custid: '1', packcode: '22'};
Object.assign(item, modal);
```

...but I don't see a need for it here, and note that there's no ongoing link between `modal` and `item`.

**Live Example:**

```js
var item = {
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "asdf976"
  },
  "Categories": [{
    "mainmodels": [{
      "submodels": [{
          "price": "2000",
          "submodelname": "lumia021",
          "Remainingphones": "0",
          "Bookedphones": "0",
          "Numofphones": "10"
        }, {
          "price": "2000",
          "submodelname": "lumia341",
          "Remainingphones": "5",
          "Bookedphones": "5",
          "Numofphones": "10"
        }

      ],
      "Status": "Active",
      "modelname": "lumia",
      "fromdate": "2016-04-01T16:39:12.051Z",
      "todate": "2016-04-31T19:19:44.051Z"
    }],
    "brand": "nokia"
  }],
  "rank": "1",
  "name": "first"
};
item.custid = '1';
item.packcode = '22';
// Note: Just using JSON for *display*
document.body.innerHTML =
  "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(item, null, 2) + "</pre>";
```

Or with `Object.assign` (requires an up-to-date browser or a shim):

```js
var item = {
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "asdf976"
  },
  "Categories": [{
    "mainmodels": [{
      "submodels": [{
          "price": "2000",
          "submodelname": "lumia021",
          "Remainingphones": "0",
          "Bookedphones": "0",
          "Numofphones": "10"
        }, {
          "price": "2000",
          "submodelname": "lumia341",
          "Remainingphones": "5",
          "Bookedphones": "5",
          "Numofphones": "10"
        }

      ],
      "Status": "Active",
      "modelname": "lumia",
      "fromdate": "2016-04-01T16:39:12.051Z",
      "todate": "2016-04-31T19:19:44.051Z"
    }],
    "brand": "nokia"
  }],
  "rank": "1",
  "name": "first"
};
var modal = {
  custid: '1',
  packcode: '22'
};
Object.assign(item, modal);
// Note: Just using JSON for *display*
document.body.innerHTML =
  "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(item, null, 2) + "</pre>";
```